# Map the Right Alt to Right Control in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard-layout, emacs

I am using Xubuntu 16.04 and I want to try out Emacs. I think binding the Right Alt key to Right Control key would help. I already tried using `setxkbmap` but it did not work.

I did this :
`setxkbmap -option ctrl:ctrl_ralt`. I even put this in the application autostart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems this has been changed to the `ctrl:ralt_rctrl` option, but the documentation in the base.lst file has not been updated. So try that. Not sure where to file the bug report for this.